# How to define a range of bits in XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to use a datatype in XML that refers to 4 bits of a byte, and other 4 bits are meant for different purposes. Like first 4 bits 0..3 are used to denote error code and bit 4, 5,6 and bit 7 for some other tasks.
How to achieve this in XML.

```
<DataItem DataType="Unsigned8" Length="1" TextId="T_ErrorCode" UseAsBits="true">
  <BitDataItem BitOffset="0" TextId="T_4bit_errorcode" />    ---> Line 125
```

Can i use:
    <...  BitOffset="0..3" TextId="T_4bit_errorcode" />

This shows the below error with:

### Edit:

With MSXML 4.0:

Line Message 
125 Error parsing '0..3' as unsignedByte datatype.
The attribute: 'BitOffset' has an invalid value according to its data type.

With Xerces:

Line Message 
125 value '0..3' does not match regular expression facet '[+-]?[0-9]+' 
129 more than one decimal point encountered

I am validating against a schema, but i am not sure how to find it. I am new to XML.
I just want to know how to represent the range of bits. is there any data type for bit ranges or i have to create a new user defined type.

The initial line of XML contains:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
```

### Edit 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="GSDML-Stylesheet-HTML-V2.2.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<ISO15745Profile xmlns="http://www.profibus.com/GSDML/2003/11/DeviceProfile" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.profibus.com/GSDML/2003/11/DeviceProfile  ..\XSD\GSDML-DeviceProfile-v2.2.xsd">

<ProfileHeader>
```

I hope the schema file i have add new data type is referred with schemalocation ?.

Can you please show me how to represent the string as bits.

Comment: @Mapper: i have edited with error details. I validate with schema, but i am not sure how to find it out.

Comment: Ah, well - `unsignedByte` sounds like it should be an integer number between 0 and 255, which `0..3` is not. So you'll have to create your own datatype, possibly as a restriction of `xs:string` that matches a certain pattern. However ... I must say I still don't quite understand your situation; if you don't know "how to find" your schema, you cannot add any data types therein. And the "initial line of XML" looks quite like the start of an Xml Schema to me, not the document you're showing a part of above.

Comment: Sorry, now i have pasted the initial lines of the XML file which i am using.

Comment: Sorry, now i have pasted the initial lines of the XML file which i am using.
My situation is just declare a 4-bit sized datatype as a type in my application. Like unsinged8 is 1 byte whole represented, likewise i want just 4-bits to represent a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're always going to refer to 4 bits (and no less), why not just use an integer value to indicate the first bit of the range?:

```
0 -> 0..3
1 -> 1..4
2 -> 2..5
3 -> 3..6
4 -> 4..7
```

You certainly can't use the value "0..3" in an attribute with datatype unsignedByte, because it's not a numeric value at all.

Comment: Thaks ! I will try this. As i am new to XML, i thought there must be a way to address BitRange data type which i can use. It seem there is no such data type and i have to create my own data type to achieve this.